# View full Extent Report using Klov

Tags: automated-tests, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I have recently implemented Klov in extent reports and I would like to know if there is a ways to view the full extent report from the Klov dashboard. I have noticed that the report that is view-able using Klov is not as in depth as the previous extent report and would like to know if there is a more in depth report for Klov?

Answer (score 1):

Well Klov and extent are generating almost the same report - check in Klov under Builds and click on View All Tests Icon.

Comment: I have done this but it does not contain as much as the htmlreporter we have used in the past, such as when I view in klov it does not break down the scenario it just simply states whether it has passed or failed

Comment: What differences do you notice?  I don't see anything different other than timestamps...

Comment: when using cucumber bdd it is showing my scenario but it is not showing individual steps such as given, and, when, then, etc. where as the html reporter is breaking down the scenario. I am not sure if possibly it is a configuration error on my part? I also know that version 4 should be coming out very soon so I am eager to check it out

Comment: yes, it works correctly on 1 of my projects but not the other so I am going to wait until version 4 comes out, which should be soon, and fix all the issues at once